# How to create custom type serializer for ASP.NET configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want to create a custom `TimeSpan` type, and I need to keep its serialization behavior as the `TimeSpan`, in appsettings.json for example, this is possible:

```
"TimeSpanProperty":"01:30:45"
```

For the new type, I need the same behavior:

```
"CustomTimeSpanProperty":"02:30:45"
```

Here's an initial implementation of `CustomTimeSpan` type:

```
public readonly struct CustomTimeSpan
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeSpan;
    public readonly TimeSpan Value => _timeSpan;

    public CustomTimeSpan(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        _timeSpan = timeSpan;
    }

    // Implicit operator to convert to total milliseconds
    public static implicit operator long(CustomTimeSpan customTimeSpan)
    {
        return (long)customTimeSpan.Value.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

I found very few resources on this topic, the best I could do is creating a `JsonConverter`-based type:

```
public class CustomTimeSpanConverter : JsonConverter<CustomTimeSpan>
{
    public override CustomTimeSpan Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            string timeSpanString = reader.GetString()!;
            if (TimeSpan.TryParse(timeSpanString, out TimeSpan timestamp))
            {
                return new CustomTimeSpan(timestamp);
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException("Invalid timestamp format");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, CustomTimeSpan value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        TimeSpan timeOfDay = value.Value;
        writer.WriteStringValue(timeOfDay.ToString(@"hh:mm:ss.fff"));
    }
}
```

The thing is that I don't now how to register this type into the configuration infrastructure of my ASP.NET project, this seems the wrong place to put in:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new CustomTimeSpanConverter());
            });
```

It doesn't sound like it will let the configuration provider use my custom JSON converter.

So my question is: is it even possible to customize the configuration serialization, if it is, then how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, configuration is not always JSON, there a lot of [configuration providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configuration-providers) like environment variables, key vaults, XML files, etc., so configuration is treated as key-value pairs and the JSON config does not affect it in any way.

As far as I know the configuration binder is not very extensible at the moment, so the only option is to bind to `TimeSpan` and then "manually" configure needed type in the code (another would be changing the `struct` to have non-readonly `Value` property and using the JSON object with it).

See also the [Custom binders for mapping config string values to types known to the composition root](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36540) github issue.